Windows 11 Enterprise/Pro SAMBA access error
Windows 11 Pro/Enterprise starting with version 24H2 by default cannot access guest Samba shares and gives this dialog which doesn't accept any usernames/passwords:
"Enter network credentials"
With Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise you could simply enable "Enable Insecure Guest Logons" group policy setting and you're good to go, however that doesn't work with Windows 11 Pro/Enterprise, it gives either of these errors:
Accessing by IP address:
**Windows can't find '\\192.168.10.10\'. Check the spelling or try again.**

Accessing by hostname:
Network Error
**Windows cannot access \\hostname**
Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network.
To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose.

See details
Error Code: 0x80070035
The network path was not found.

This is due:

In Windows 11 24H2, we've made two major security changes that can affect mapping drives to third-party consumer NAS or routers with USB storage:

By default, SMB signing is required on all connections. This increases your security by preventing tampering on the network and stops relay attacks that send your credentials to malicious servers.
Guest fallback is disabled on Windows 11 Pro edition. This increases your security when connecting to untrustworthy devices. Guest allows you to connect to an SMB server with no username or password. While convenient for the maker of your NAS, it means that your device can be tricked into connecting to a malicious server without prompting for credentials, then given ransomware or having your data stolen.
If signing isn't supported by your third-party device, you may get error:


0xc000a000
-1073700864
STATUS_INVALID_SIGNATURE
The cryptographic signature is invalid


If guest access is required by your third party, you may get error:
You can't access this shared folder because your organization's security policies block unauthenticated guest access. These policies help protect your PC from unsafe or malicious devices on the network

0x80070035
0x800704f8
The network path was not found
System error 3227320323 has occurred

Here's the relevant SAMBA configuration:
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    security = user
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    guest account = nobody
    map to guest = Bad User

    printing = bsd
    printcap name = /dev/null
    load printers = no
    cups options = raw
    disable spoolss = yes


In order to enable "guest" access from Windows 11 Enterprise you have to do the following:

Open Group Policy, go to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Lanman Workstation, double click "Enable Insecure Guest Logons" and choose "Enabled", click OK.



Open Local Security Policy, go to Local Policies -> Security Options and find


Microsoft Network Client: Digitally Sign Communications (always)
Microsoft Network Client: Digitally Sign Communications (if server agrees)

Set both of these to "Disabled".

